# Object is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, minidom

I have a problem with my code. 
The program is designed to parse the file, select it with the information and save them in the list of objects of the class.

But first - it does not save them correctly. In fact, nothing does save, it returns empty records.

I tried to create a minimum of code entirely and work on it. Next it does not work. I can not display objects do not know if correctly saves them in the class. I also changed the xml to a smaller and a sample to see if the search is a mistake.

I think on this for a long time, I'm running out of ideas, I ask for a clue.

Minimum code

```
from xml.dom import minidom

class Prot():
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name

    def addname(self, name):
        for k in range(len(entry_list)):
            names = entry_list[k].getElementsByTagName("Names")
            for u in range(len(names)):
                nam = names[u].getElementsByTagName("Name")
                name.append(nam[u].firstChild.nodeValue)
                print(nam[u].firstChild.nodeValue)

xml = minidom.parse('RESIDUES.XML')

entry_list = xml.getElementsByTagName("Entry")
mod_list = []
for e in range(len(entry_list)):
    m = Prot(e)
    mod_list.append(m)
```

xml - one record

```
<Entry id="AA0003">
<Header>
<Code>AA0003</Code>
<Dates>
<CreationDate>31-Mar-1995</CreationDate>
<StrucRevDate>31-Mar-1995</StrucRevDate>
<TextChngDate>30-Sep-2010</TextChngDate>
</Dates>
</Header>
<Names>
<Name>L-asparagine</Name>
<AlternateName>2,4-bis(azanyl)-4-oxobutanoic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>2,4-diamino-4-oxobutanoic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>2-amino-3-carbamoylpropanoic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>2-amino-4-butanediamic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>2-aminosuccinamic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>2-aminosuccinic acid 4-amide</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>alpha-amino-beta-carbamylpropionic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>alpha-aminosuccinamic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>aspartic acid 4-amide</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>aspartic acid beta-amide</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>beta-asparagine</AlternateName>
<SystematicName>(2S)-2-amino-4-butanediamic acid</SystematicName>
<Xref>CAS:70-47-3</Xref>
<Xref>ChEBI:50347</Xref>
<Xref>PDBHET:ASN</Xref>
</Names>
<FormulaBlock>
<Formula>C 4 H 6 N 2 O 2</Formula>
<Weight type="chemical">114.10</Weight>
<Weight type="physical">114.042927</Weight>
</FormulaBlock>
<CorrectionBlock uids="AA0003" label="ASN">
<Formula>C 0 H 0 N 0 O 0</Formula>
<Weight type="chemical">0.00</Weight>
<Weight type="physical">0.000000</Weight>
</CorrectionBlock>
<CorrectionBlock uids="AA0004" label="ASP">
<Formula>C 0 H 1 N 1 O -1</Formula>
<Weight type="chemical">-0.98</Weight>
<Weight type="physical">-0.984016</Weight>
</CorrectionBlock>
<ReferenceBlock>
<Authors>
<Author>Vauquelin, L.N.</Author>
<Author>Robiquet, P.J.</Author>
</Authors>
<Citation>Ann. Chim. 57, 88-93, 1806</Citation>
<Title>
Découverte d'un nouveau principe végétal dans les Asperges (Asparagus sativus, Linn.) [The discovery of a new plant principle in asparagus (Asparagus sativus, L.)].
</Title>
<Note>article in French; isolation and naming</Note>
</ReferenceBlock>
<ReferenceBlock>
<Authors>
<Author>Drenth, J.</Author>
<Author>Jansonius, J.N.</Author>
<Author>Koekoek, R.</Author>
<Author>Swen, H.M.</Author>
<Author>Wolthers, B.G.</Author>
</Authors>
<Citation>Nature 218, 929-932, 1968</Citation>
<Title>Structure of papain.</Title>
<Xref>DOI:10.1038/218929a0</Xref>
<Xref>PMID:5681232</Xref>
<Note>
asparagine as an active site residue in a thiol proteinase
</Note>
</ReferenceBlock>
<ReferenceBlock>
<Authors>
<Anonymous/>
<Group>
IUPAC-IUB Joint Commission on Biochemical Nomenclature (JCBN)
</Group>
</Authors>
<Citation>Eur. J. Biochem. 138, 9-37, 1984</Citation>
<Title>
Nomenclature and symbolism for amino acids and peptides. Recommendations 1983.
</Title>
<Xref>DOI:10.1111/j.1432-1033.1984.tb07877.x</Xref>
<Xref>PMID:6692818</Xref>
<Note>
standard three-letter and one-letter symbols, and nomenclature
</Note>
</ReferenceBlock>
<ReferenceBlock>
<Authors>
<Author>Curnow, A.W.</Author>
<Author>Tumbula, D.L.</Author>
<Author>Pelaschier, J.T.</Author>
<Author>Min, B.</Author>
<Author>Soll, D.</Author>
</Authors>
<Citation>
Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 95, 12838-12843, 1998
</Citation>
<Title>
Glutamyl-tRNA(Gln) amidotransferase in Deinococcus radiodurans may be confined to asparagine biosynthesis.
</Title>
<Xref>DOI:10.1073/pnas.95.22.12838</Xref>
<Xref>PMID:9789001</Xref>
<Note>
"mischarged" aspartyl-tRNA(Asn) is amidated by glutamyl-tRNA(Gln) amidotransferase in Deinococcus radiodurans
</Note>
</ReferenceBlock>
<ReferenceBlock>
<Authors>
<Author>Paradisi, F.</Author>
<Author>Dean, J.L.</Author>
<Author>Geoghegan, K.F.</Author>
<Author>Engel, P.C.</Author>
</Authors>
<Citation>Biochemistry 44, 3636-3643, 2005</Citation>
<Title>
Spontaneous chemical reversion of an active site mutation: deamidation of an asparagine residue replacing the catalytic aspartic acid of glutamate dehydrogenase.
</Title>
<Xref>DOI:10.1021/bi047679u</Xref>
<Xref>PMID:15736973</Xref>
<Note>
an Asp to Asn mutation at an enzyme active site seemingly has partial activity; however, the asparagine form is shown to be inactive, and enhanced spontaneous deamidation results in the partial recovery of activity
</Note>
</ReferenceBlock>
<ReferenceBlock>
<Authors>
<Author>Kolodkin-Gal, I.</Author>
<Author>Hazan, R.</Author>
<Author>Gaathon, A.</Author>
<Author>Carmeli, S.</Author>
<Author>Engelberg-Kulka, H.</Author>
</Authors>
<Citation>Science 318, 652-655, 2007</Citation>
<Title>
A linear pentapeptide is a quorum-sensing factor required for mazEF-mediated cell death in Escherichia coli.
</Title>
<Xref>DOI:10.1126/science.1147248</Xref>
<Xref>PMID:17962566</Xref>
<Note>
enzymatic amidation of an aspartic acid residue in a peptide; the enzyme is currently identified by an activity that is different from the new activity
</Note>
</ReferenceBlock>
<Comment>
Some bacteria or archaea incorporate asparagine produced by the amidation of aspartyl-tRNA(Asn).
</Comment>
<GeneratingEnzyme>
<EnzymeName link="ASN">aspartate--tRNA(Asn) ligase (EC 6.1.1.23)</EnzymeName>
<EnzymeName link="ASN">
asparaginyl-tRNA synthase (glutamine-hydrolysing) (EC 6.3.5.6)
</EnzymeName>
<EnzymeName link="ASP">aspartate--ammonia ligase (EC 6.3.1.1)</EnzymeName>
</GeneratingEnzyme>
<SequenceCode link="ASN">
<SequenceSpec>N</SequenceSpec>
<Abbreviation>Asn</Abbreviation>
<Xref>PSI-MOD:00012</Xref>
</SequenceCode>
<SequenceCode link="ASP">
<SequenceSpec>D</SequenceSpec>
<Xref>PSI-MOD:01185</Xref>
</SequenceCode>
<Source>natural</Source>
<Features>
<Feature type="UniProt" key="act_site____n" link="ASN">ACT_SITE</Feature>
<Feature type="UniProt" key="mod_res__amidated aspartic acid__d" link="ASP">MOD_RES Amidated aspartic acid</Feature>
</Features>
<Image src="/images/AA0003.GIF" alt="DUMMY.GIF"/>
<Model src="/models/AA0003.PDB"/>
</Entry>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are expecting as result. `addname` is never called. Iterating through `range(len(entry_list))` results in 0, 1, 2, .. len-1 - may be not what you expect?

Comment: It should be here just L-asparagine. I called function add name when `for e in range(len(entry_list)):
    m = Prot(e)
    mod_list.append(m) `. I create a new object class is done add name and adds the result to the list of objects.It's correct?

Comment: A XML file has one root element. When you write 'one record' at your example, is this a usual file or do you have multiple 'Entry' elements inside another root element?

Comment: Mutiple Entry, it's just a example.

Answer (score 0):

I really like `xml.etree` for this kind of task. Supposing your xml example has multiple `Entry` records inside an other element, I used this xml file to test my code:

```
<Records>
<Entry id="AA0003">
<Header>
<Code>AA0003</Code>
</Header>
<Names>
<Name>L-asparagine</Name>
<AlternateName>2,4-bis(azanyl)-4-oxobutanoic acid</AlternateName>
<AlternateName>2,4-diamino-4-oxobutanoic acid</AlternateName>
</Names>
</Entry>
<Entry id="??????">
<Header>
<Code>??????</Code>
</Header>
<Names>
<Name>N-Acetylglucosamine</Name>
</Names>
</Entry>
</Records>
```

Here is the code to parse the xml file:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree=ElementTree.parse('RESIDUES.XML')
for entry in tree.findall('Entry'):
    print entry.find('Names/Name').text
```

This results in:

```
L-asparagine
N-Acetylglucosamine
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to carry out such changes in function  and see if will work. OK, still not, because when i trying print out results it's `''list' object has no attribute 'name'` -> ` print(mod_list.name[2])`. It have to save in list of objects class and I would after that print it out to see results.